# preferences.d for ununtu 14.04 not working, what do I do wrong?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-14.04, preferences

I have repo declared here:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list
# Packages for Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop, Version 5, on Ubuntu 14.04 amd64
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh trusty-cdh5.3.3 contrib
deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh trusty-cdh5.3.3 contrib
```

and preferences here:

```
cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/cloudera.pref
Package: *
Pin: release o=Cloudera, l=Cloudera
Pin-Priority: 501
```

Then I have "problem" package. It should be taken from "Cloudera" repo. That is the reason for using preferences.
Described here:http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#topic_4_4_1_unique_2__section_dfx_p51_nj_unique_2

When I ask apt to show me package Origin I see that it's taken from Ubuntu repo, not from Cloudera repo:

```
sudo apt-cache  show libzookeeper-java
Package: libzookeeper-java
Priority: optional
Section: universe/java
Installed-Size: 1335
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: zookeeper
Version: 3.4.5+dfsg-1
Depends: libjline-java, liblog4j1.2-java (>> 1.2.15-8), libnetty-java, libslf4j-java, libxerces2-java
Recommends: libzookeeper-java-doc
Filename: pool/universe/z/zookeeper/libzookeeper-java_3.4.5+dfsg-1_all.deb
Size: 1237412
MD5sum: 2d2793872aa6faf93cce49dd85600b95
SHA1: cdda8da7cd5c7a4be68c02e39a818cd48fd81afd
SHA256: e09f600f09a425446d1456b758614018699d45e17214577dd09b0e8637fef9a9
Description-en: Core Java libraries for zookeeper
 ZooKeeper is a centralized, reliable, service for maintaining configuration
 information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and group
 services. All of these kinds of services are used in some form or another by
 distributed applications.
 .
 This package contains the java .jar files.
Description-md5: 9d8746036f857b6258f6cc81bcc7fbb8
Homepage: http://zookeeper.apache.org
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

What do I do wrong?

P.S.
It could be a problem:

```
apt-cache showpkg zookeeper
Package: zookeeper
Versions: 
3.4.5+dfsg-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 0a45f324b8251b96598372f069b4c228
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 0a45f324b8251b96598372f069b4c228

3.4.5+cdh5.3.3+84-1.cdh5.3.3.p0.8~trusty-cdh5.3.3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.cloudera.com_cdh5_ubuntu_trusty_amd64_cdh_dists_trusty-cdh5.3.3_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.cloudera.com_cdh5_ubuntu_trusty_amd64_cdh_dists_trusty-cdh5.3.3_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: b4638643f4a1a2e968cdf61ab4ddcf41
```

Looks like zookeeper is not taken from Cloudera repo because of preferences misconfiguration?

Comment: The important bit is the output of `apt-cache policy zookeeper`.

Comment: I've added it to answer. I suppose it was my fault, I had to completely remove all stuff came from other repos

Answer (score 0):

So I've cleaned all:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove all_custom_packages
```

and then rerun `sudo apt-get install things-i-need`
It started to work.

Here is output for command

```
apt-cache policy zookeeper
    zookeeper:
      Installed: 3.4.5+cdh5.3.3+84-1.cdh5.3.3.p0.8~trusty-cdh5.3.3
      Candidate: 3.4.5+cdh5.3.3+84-1.cdh5.3.3.p0.8~trusty-cdh5.3.3
      Version table:
         3.4.5+dfsg-1 0
            500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     *** 3.4.5+cdh5.3.3+84-1.cdh5.3.3.p0.8~trusty-cdh5.3.3 0
            501 http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh/ trusty-cdh5.3.3/contrib amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```